# I was stuck on Exception Handling in Python Requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Contributors.

I'm writing a get title of web program using python requests module.
I wanna do error handling, but i was stuck.

This is my code.

```
for i in result:
try: 
    print("URL : {}".format(i[0]))
    req = requests.get(i[0], headers=headers, timeout=15)
    html = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    title = soup.title.string
    print(title)

except requests.ConnectionError as e:
    print("Error : Network Connection Error <{}>".format(e))

except requests.Response.raise_for_status() as e:
    print("Error: Invalid Response Error.")

except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
    print("Error: Timeout Error.")

except requests.TooManyRedirects as e:
    print("Error: Too many Redirects")

except:
    print("Error: Unknown Error.")
```

This is Python Console's Answers:

```
URL : url.com
Nice URL
URL : http://0x92B9BDB9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1088, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1126, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1084, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 922, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 857, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 834, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 512, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 503, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 330, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 562, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 391, in _make_request
    (self.host, timeout_obj.connect_timeout))
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool object at 0x7f0e820c69b0>, 'Connection to 0x92B9BDB9 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gettitle.py", line 49, in <module>
    req = requests.get(i[0], headers=headers, timeout=15)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 558, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 387, in send
    raise Timeout(e)
requests.exceptions.Timeout: (<urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool object at 0x7f0e820c69b0>, 'Connection to 0x92B9BDB9 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gettitle.py", line 58, in <module>
    except requests.Response.raise_for_status() as e:
TypeError: raise_for_status() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

How can i fix it?
Thanks so much for letting me know!

Comment: It looks like you need to instantiate `request.Response` before calling `raise_for_status()` on it.

Comment: What do you expect `except requests.Response.raise_for_status()` to do?  Even if you were calling it correctly (`req` is a `Response` object, so you could use `except req.raise_for_status()`), what is your intent?  `requests.get()` will not throw exceptions for "normal" responses such as 404 or 401, which is what you'd get from `raise_for_status()`.

Comment: @JohnGordon : I got it. thanks for helping me!

Comment: @CoryMadden Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `request.get`, I kept having the same problem like you did. I found out that I was using my VPN. When I turned it off everything got back to normal!